# Getting the error in passing parameter to a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_InsertHashBinMinHash
    @Id INT,
    @HashBin BIGINT,
    @HashTable INT,
    @SubFingerprintId BIGINT,
    @Seqno INT
AS

INSERT INTO HashBinsMinHash (
    HashBin,
    HashTable,
    Seqno,
    SubFingerprintId
    ) OUTPUT inserted.Id
VALUES
(
    @HashBin, @HashTable, @Seqno, @SubFingerprintId
);
```

When I am running the program I am getting the following error:

> procedure or function sp_insertHashBin expects parameter @Seqno which was not supplied

But I am passing 4 parameters to procedure

Comment: It takes 5 parameters, your only passing 4...

Comment: I think you are not using/passing Id parameter value. Either use id= null or pass the @id value.

Answer (score 0):

There is your problem: `sp_InsertHashBinMinHash` expects 5 parameters (`Id`, `HashBin`, `HashTable`, `SubFingerprintId` and `Seqno`). You are only calling it with 4. So one is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite it as

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_InsertHashBinMinHash
    @HashBin BIGINT,
    @HashTable INT,
    @SubFingerprintId BIGINT,
    @Seqno INT,
    @Id INT OUT
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO HashBinsMinHash (
    HashBin,
    HashTable,
    Seqno,
    SubFingerprintId
    ) 
VALUES
(
    @HashBin, @HashTable, @Seqno, @SubFingerprintId
);

set @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
select @id
END
```

And, passing values to your procedure from C#, add parameter @Id with proper Direction property.